# Material-UI v1 Drawer component isn't working in the iOS 13 beta build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, ios13

While prepping for the latest iOS release, expected next month, the main navigation for our site is no longer functioning when using an iOS device on the latest beta (iOS13). The drawer opens as expected, but clicking on any of the contained menu items doesn't trigger an onclick action and the drawer simply closes(or remains open in the desktop view without triggering the action). The menuitems themselves visually react to the tap, but nothing else.

Unfortunately upgrading the version of material-ui isn't an option

Comment: I personally find material-ui to be notorious for constant breaking changes. I don't have a true solution for you, but if it's only one or two components that aren't working, then I suggest you either temporarily build a component with identical behavior yourself or check out the material ui source code and see what other recourses you have

Comment: Hi Richtor - welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you able to post videos, GIFs, or images of the issue at hand to help us better understand the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't specifically the Drawer, but the function that is used to close the drawer when the user clicks away from the Drawer. Specifically the issue was in our implementation of the the ClickAwayListener of material-ui. Once we removed that it was working fine.